# Print multiple data sets in a range

Tags: oop, printing, range

I've made a small program that is supposed to read data in a range input it into an object oriented program, and then return the full data set. the issue is that when I run the file it only return data on the third procedure

I tried printing other procedure sets but idk how to do that, i'm thinking this will only work if i replace the procedures from generic to specific. as in instead of Procedure name for all of them procedures 1, 2, and 3

```
for i in range (3):
    procedure_name = ('Physical Exam')
    date_of =  ("Nov 6th 2022")
    doctor =  ('Dr. Irvine')
    charge = ('$ 250.00')

    procedure_name = ('X-ray')
    date_of =  ("Nov 6th 2022")
    doctor =  ('Dr. Jamison')
    charge = ('$ 500.00')

    procedure_name = ('Blood test')
    date_of =  ("Nov 6th 2022")
    doctor =  ('Dr. Smith')
    charge = ('$ 200.00')

    procedure = HW6_RODRIGUEZ_1.Procedure(procedure_name,date_of,doctor,charge)
print(f'Procedure {i+1}')
print(procedure)
print(i, end=" ")
```

if **name** == '**main**':
main()

Answer (score 1):

So, I think you may have misunderstood some things when it comes to variables, OOP and looping.

When you define a variable, that variable is set to the last value it is assigned. So if you have the following code:

```
a = 1
a = 2
a = 3
```

The final value of the variable 'a' will be 3, as that is the last value it is assigned.

As for loops, whatever you have written in a for loop will be repeated for a specified number of times. This means if you want to write a loop that prints "hello" 5 times, you'd write the following:

```
for i in range(5):
    print("hello")
```

What your loop is essentially doing is overwriting the same 3 variables 3 times over, this won't be assigning new values to an object.

When it comes to creating an object that you assign variable to, you need to first write the code for your class. Your class can have attributes like the variables you've stated. It could look something like this:

```
class procedure:
    def __init__(self, procedure_name, date_of, doctor, charge):
        self.procedure_name = procedure_name
        self.date_of = date_of
        self.doctor = doctor
        self.charge = charge
```

Now, to set up a procedure object, you just assign a variable to procedure with the desired variables as parameters, like so:

```
new = procedure('X-ray','Nov 6th 2022','Dr. Jamison','$ 500.00')
```

And to access a variable, you just need to write procedureName.attribute. For example, using the object I just set up:

```
print(new.doctor)
```

Would output 'Dr. Jamison'.

If you want to store a bunch of them, I would recommend storing them in a list or a dictionary, depending on how you want to look them up.

I hope this helps! If you are new to programming, I would recommend some simpler programs such as a program that prints the nursery rhyme 10 green bottles using loops, or maybe making a quiz.

Best of luck.